# Building cph ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've cloned a github docker setup which uses docker-compose. the code working well as confirmed by the writer, I think I am missing something during the configuration

According to the instructions I am running the following command :

```
EXPERIMENT=${linear} docker-compose up --build
```

My docker-compose.yml has the following code :

```
cph:
build: ./cph
dockerfile: Dockerfile.${EXPERIMENT}
volumes:
  - ../deepsurv:/DeepSurv/deepsurv
  - ./scripts:/scripts
  - ./data/${EXPERIMENT}:/shared/data
  - ./results/${EXPERIMENT}:/shared/results

deepsurv:
build: ./deepsurv
dockerfile: Dockerfile.${EXPERIMENT}
volumes:
  - ../deepsurv:/DeepSurv/deepsurv
  - ./scripts:/scripts
  - ./data/${EXPERIMENT}:/shared/data
  - ./results/${EXPERIMENT}:/shared/results

rsf:
build: ./rsf
dockerfile: Dockerfile.${EXPERIMENT}
volumes:
  - ../deepsurv:/DeepSurv/deepsurv
  - ./scripts:/scripts
  - ./data/${EXPERIMENT}:/shared/data
  - ./results/${EXPERIMENT}:/shared/results
```

I am using the variable Experiment = linear to call the first docker but I got a warning and the following error :

```
 WARNING: The linear variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
 Building cph
 ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile.
```

The structure of my docker-compose.yml is the following :
/DeepSurv/experiments$ tree

/DeepSurv/experiments$ tree

```
.
├── cph
│   ├── Dockerfile.gaussian
│   ├── Dockerfile.gbsg
│   ├── Dockerfile.linear
│   ├── Dockerfile.metabric
│   ├── Dockerfile.support
│   ├── Dockerfile.treatment
│   └── Dockerfile.whas
├── data
│   ├── gaussian
│   │   └── gaussian_survival_data.h5
│   ├── gbsg
│   │   └── gbsg_cancer_train_test.h5
│   ├── linear
│   │   ├── linear_survival_data.h5
│   │   └── logs
│   │       └── tensorboard_
│   │           └── shared
│   │               └── data
│   │                   ├── linear_survival_data.h5_320635bd-e6f6-49f9-    ba02-2d2aba6d25d2
│   │                   │   └──     events.out.tfevents.1501950449.ebe916c018ac
│   │                   ├── linear_survival_data.h5_88d7b4e3-5a3b-    4380-8b22-7c7a4b0aa1ee
│   │                   │   └──      events.out.tfevents.1501951016.152ea285d90e
│   │                   ├──      linear_survival_data.h5_e215d084-3302-4248-939d-f5e43cfe63b5
│   │                   │   └──      events.out.tfevents.1501950494.152ea285d90e
│   │                   └──      linear_survival_data.h5_ea209c15-00d7-4a57-8fc8-046e08038eba
│   │                       └──      events.out.tfevents.1501950372.411602be3a6f
│   ├── metabric
│   │   └── metabric_IHC4_clinical_train_test.h5
│   ├── support
│   │   ├── logs
│   │   │   └── tensorboard_
│   │   │       └── shared
│   │   │           └── data
│   │   │               ├── support_train_test.h5_b1f908ae-d03c-4f7c-aab9-     ae01ac9d31f7
│   │   │               │   └──     events.out.tfevents.1501953943.cd9ea224808d
│   │   │               └── support_train_test.h5_df8bcb48-c77e-46f8-    b33c-112cb940a285
│   │   │                   └──     events.out.tfevents.1501954035.bf1b5f1da709
│   │   └── support_train_test.h5
│   ├── treatment
│   │   └── sim_treatment_dataset.h5
│   └── whas
│       └── whas_train_test.h5
├── deepsurv
│   ├── Dockerfile.gaussian
│   ├── Dockerfile.gbsg
│   ├── Dockerfile.linear
│   ├── Dockerfile.metabric
│   ├── Dockerfile.support
│   ├── Dockerfile.treatment
│   ├── Dockerfile.whas
│   └── models
│       ├── gaussian_model_0.json
│       ├── gaussian_model_selu_revision.0.json
│       ├── gaussian_model_selu_revision.1.json
│       ├── gbsg_model_selu_revision.0.json
│       ├── gbsg_selu_adam_model_0.json
│       ├── linear_model_selu_0.json
│       ├── linear_model_selu_revision.0.json
│       ├── linear_model_selu_revision.json
│       ├── metabric_IHC4_clinical_adam_0.json
│       ├── metabric_model_selu_revision.0.json
│       ├── support_model_selu_revision.0.json
│       ├── support_selu_model_adam_0.json
│       ├── treatment_adam_selu_model_0.json
│       ├── treatment_model_selu_revision.0.json
│       ├── whas_model_selu_0.json
│       └── whas_model_selu_revision.0.json
├── docker-compose-original.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── README.md
├── rsf
│   ├── Dockerfile.gaussian
│   ├── Dockerfile.gbsg
│   ├── Dockerfile.linear
│   ├── Dockerfile.metabric
│   ├── Dockerfile.support
│   ├── Dockerfile.treatment
│   └── Dockerfile.whas
└── scripts
├── cph_run.py
├── deepsurv_run.py
```

The docker compose version is :

```
docker-compose version 
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown
docker-py version: 1.9.0
CPython version: 2.7.12
```

OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Can you please help me overcome this error ?

Comment: `${linear}` doesn't set EXPERIMENT=linear, it sets EXPERIMENT=(the value of the variable 'linear'). Is that what you mean to do?

Comment: ** Exactly** there is a docker in the "cph" called " Docker.linear" I am trying to build , please look at the tree above

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
EXPERIMENT=linear docker-compose up --build
```

as you want it to use the actual word "linear"

Just tried with:

```
.
├── cph
│   └── Dockerfile.linear
└── docker-compose.yml
```

and this docker-compose.yml

```
cph:
  build: ./cph
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.${EXPERIMENT}
```

and the Dockerfile.linear:

```
FROM alpine:latest
```

and the above mentioned command and it works fine like this. You do have to run the docker-compose command from the folder where the docker-compose.yml file resides and the rest of the folders need to be relative to that one.

Comment: I got the following :ERROR: Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml

Comment: I replaced the word "Linear" inside the docker-compose.yml but the same error persists : Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile.

Comment: Now I tried with  "EXPERIMENT=linear docker-compose up --build" , also the same error, I want to call other docker files under cph , how can I do that , I am standing in the same folder which is "experiments" folder

Comment: Have you formatted the docker-compose.yml file correctly with indentations? I do not see that in your example...

Comment: those are additional information from the readme file Experiments are run using Docker containers built off of the [floydhub](https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker) deep learning Docker images. DeepSurv can be run on either the CPU or the GPU with nvidia-docker. 

All experiments are in the `DeepSurv/experiments/` directory. 

To run an experiment, define the experiment name as an environmental variable `EXPRIMENT`and run the docker-compose file. Further details are in the `DeepSurv/experiments/` directory.

Comment: I think we are close now , the error changed now i have this : Service 'rsf' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -qq &&   apt-get install -y